# How to properly filter your route::group in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

How to properly filter your route::group in Laravel 4 ?

I have a problem with route::group filter.

They both the same thing.

The bottom route group **work**, and the top one **doesn't**. :(

They keep redirect to 404 and I don't intend to do that.

Can anybody tell me what did I do wrong ?

```
    ////////////////
    // OEM Routes //
    ////////////////

    Route::group(array('before'=>'oem'),function() {


        Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
        Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
        Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

        Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
        Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');


        });


    ////////////////////////
    //Distributor Routes  //
    ////////////////////////

     Route::group(array('before'=>'distributor'),function() {


        Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
        Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
        Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

        Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
        Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');

        Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
        Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
        Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');

        Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'MarketingMaterialController@show'));

        });
```

[image: 404 Not Found image]

**Edited Add Filters.php**

[image]

> Goals:

**User Type = Distributor**

for user()->type = "Distributor"

They can access this :

```
 Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
            Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
            Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

            Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
            Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');

            Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
            Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
            Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');
```

**User Type = Distributor + Distributor Type = OEM**

Else if user()->type = "Distributor" AND Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type ==  'OEM'

They can only access :

```
                Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
                Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
                Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

                Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
                Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');
```

Not This..

```
            Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
            Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
            Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');
```

Comment: Can you show us the two filters `distributor` and `oem`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter : I noticed, you always helped me. Thanks you for your consideration. :)

Comment: About the filters, I wanted to show it in the post since the first place, but SO won't let me - due to a lot of code. How do I post it in the comment without confuse you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm here to help ;) What do you mean by SO won't let you?

Comment: You know , when we post a lot of portion of code rather than explanation, Stack Overflow (SO) will stop you from doing that. I don't know - maybe my reputation is low.

Comment: I see, didn't about know that. Well the picture will do. I think I got the solution to your problem. I'll write an answer now :)

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks. I'll make sure to accept your answer when I get home. I've been stuck on it almost 4 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this: If you don't have a prefix defined for your groups, Laravel makes no difference between a route in one group and a route in the other (that share the same url)

Because what Laravel does first, is searching for the matching route. All the filter stuff is done afterwards (even if its a before filter).

In your case that means that, for example `Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));` in the `distributors` group, overrides the same route that has been registered before in the `oem` group

Now how do we solve that (and also make your code more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

First we will write a new filter that will replace the two you have already. Let's call it `role`

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value){
    if(Auth::user()->type == 'Distributor'){
        $authorized = true;

        if($value == 'distributor'){
            if(Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type !==  'OEM'){
                $authorized = false;
            }
        }
        else if($value == 'oem'){
            if(Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type ==  'OEM'){
                $authorized = false;
            }
        }
        else if($value == 'distributor+oem'){
            $authorized = false;
        }


        if(!$authorized){
            if(Request::ajax()){
                return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
            }
            else {
                return View::make('errors.404_auth');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know if I got your business logic in the filter 100% correct, but I hope you understand the basic principle.

And that's how you use it:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'role:distributor+oem'), function(){

    Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
    Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
    Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

    Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
    Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');

});


Route::group(array('before'=>'role:distributor'), function(){

    Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');

    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'MarketingMaterialController@show'));
});
```

#### Update

The goals you updated the question with, change it a bit...

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value){
    $roles = explode(';', $value);
    $authorized = false;
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(in_array('distributor', $roles)){
        if($user->type == 'Distributor' && $user->distributor()->first()->type != 'OEM'){
            return;
        }
    }
    if(in_array('oem', $roles)){
        if($user->type == 'Distributor' && $user->distributor()->first()->type == 'OEM'){
            return;
        }
    }


    if(Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    }
    else {
        return View::make('errors.404_auth');
    }
});
```

And the routes:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'role:distributor;oem'), function(){

    Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
    Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
    Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));

    Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
    Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');

});


Route::group(array('before'=>'role:distributor'), function(){

    Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');

    Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'MarketingMaterialController@show'));
});
```

#### Explanation

First, you find all you need to know about route filters [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters). However, that's the very short version: The filter function registered by `Route::filter('name', function(){})` gets called by Laravel with the route object, the request object and a filter parameter (`filter:parameter`) as arguments in this order.

How does this filter function in particular work?
To be able to pass multiple "roles" it uses a parameter string like `role1;role2` etc
Now in the function the string gets split (by `;`) saved in the roles array.
This array is used to perform a check if a certain role is allowed and the current user has it. If we have a match, it returns to the route. If none of the conditions are true an error is returned.

Comment: I've tried your code, it didn't seem to work. I'm pretty sure that you're very close. I've just edit my exact goal on the post. Do you mind help me tweak your code a little - to fit my condition. I'm new to this. I hope you don't mind. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @evoque2015 No I don't mind ;) I updated the answer. Hope this works

Comment: You're awesome. I don't know what to say beside that. :)

Comment: Can you kindly explain this function($route, $request, $value) a little bit ? How do you know we need 3 parameters ? and what is the value of those variables ? Where did you get them from ?

Comment: Your answer is work perfectly when, I logged in as user.type = Distributor. But, it break some of my links when I logged in as `user.type = Admin`, **OR** `user.type = something else`. Therefore, I was trying to understand your code in ** filter.php ** so maybe I can modify it myself.

Comment: Do you mind help me with similar question to this ? at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236098/how-to-make-route-filter-in-laravel-4